# Trouble getting a SPARQL query using a URI

Tags: uri, sparql, protege

I'm having trouble acquiring instances from a subclass on Protege using SPARQL. The task is to create an ontology using information from a Website. To start this I have tried to get the contact information such as the Email addresses and Phone Numbers. I have provided screenshots of the Classes and Individual Tabs below:

Classes:
[image: Classes Tab]

Individuals:
[image: Individual Tab]

I want it to display a list of the two email addresses. I heard there was a way to get them using the URI.

How do I get the URI and how do I enter it after the rdf:type in the query's code?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your screenshot, the URI of the 'Contact Email' class is `http://www.semanticweb.org/cthom/ontologies/2021/untitled-ontology-34#Contact_Email`. So, to get all instances of this class, you can use the following SPARQL query:

```
select ?contactEmail 
where { ?contactEmail a <http://www.semanticweb.org/cthom/ontologies/2021/untitled-ontology-34#Contact_Email> }
```

Tip: try one of the online SPARQL tutorials to get a bit more familiar with the language.